# Locking an XLSX file for reading and writing with FileInputStream, FileOutputStream, and RandomAccessFile

Tags: java, apache-poi, filelock

I have an excel that I want to be locked when each forked process is reading and writing to it.  Apache poi requires me to use `FileInputStream` and `FileOutputStream` for reading and writing to that file, but all the examples I've seen for locking a file for reading and writing use `RandomAccessFile` for this, but when I do this, when I call `workbook.write(os);` I get an 
`org.apache.poi.openxml4j.exceptions.OpenXML4JRuntimeException` and the **excel becomes corrupted**.  Here is some of the code:

```
try {
        RandomAccessFile raf = new RandomAccessFile(path,"rw");
        FileChannel channel = raf.getChannel();
        FileLock lock = channel.lock(0L,Long.MAX_VALUE,true);

        FileInputStream is = new FileInputStream(path);
        XSSFWorkbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(is);
        XSSFSheet sheet = workbook.getSheet(env.toUpperCase());

        Iterator<Row> rowIterator = sheet.iterator();
        //skip headers
        rowIterator.next();
        while (rowIterator.hasNext())
        {
            //reading and editing values in excel
        }

        is.close();

        FileOutputStream os = new FileOutputStream(path);   
        workbook.write(os);
        workbook.close();
        os.close();    

        lock.release();
        channel.close();
        raf.close();

    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't use `RandomAccessFile`, `FileChannel` and `FileLock` on your actual shared file, try to create and lock a separate dummy file instead. This way the process that succeeds won't see unusual locks or other activity on the Excel file.

Comment: Great suggestion! Trying something like that did not even cross my mind. Thank you.